# Import JavaScripts' library in application.js in Rails using Yarn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hadoop-yarn, sprockets

I am using **Yarn** to install some libraries into my application on Rails.
I recently installed [ldcolorpicker](https://github.com/loadingio/ldcolorpicker) but it's like my application can't reach it.
I used the appropriate command given by Yarn `yarn add @loadingio/ldcolorpicker` and imported on my `application.js` too using `//= require @loadingio/ldcolorpicker/index.js`. But it's like the import was not successfully done, because my js console gives me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ldcolorpicker.init is not a function
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: @crodev version 6.1.4

Comment: Can you please show the code where you called ldcolor picker?

Comment: @crodev sure `<input type="input" data-toggle="ldcolorpicker">

<script type="text/javascript">
    ldcolorpicker.init();
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Update: It is like I cannot import in my `application.js` packages with `@`. I also added the new `amcharts4` with the same issue too. Any advice?